# What is the expected value of the division of a random variable by a sum of random variables?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

With $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ being independent random variables, how can I compute $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}\right]$?

Is $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2+X_3}\right] = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]}{\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_2\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X_3\right]}$? If not, how is it  calculated?

Thank you in advance for any clarification.

Comment: Are you also assuming the variables all have the same distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a famous "folk theorem" residual to my undergrad classes, namely that
$$\mathbb E[X/Y] = \mathbb E[X] \big/ \mathbb E[Y]$$
and it is often permeates during exams, as it makes computing much easier. Sadly, the equality does not hold in general, even when $X$ and $Y$ are independent (due to Jensen's inequality).

In the case of $\mathbb E[X_1/X_1+X_2+X_3]$, numerator and denominator are dependent, which usually makes the computation more difficult. However, in the very special case when the three $X_i$'s are iid, $X_i/X_1+X_2+X_3$ has the same distribution for all three $i$'s and this leads to an obvious conclusion concerning the expectation of any of them. **Assuming this expectation exists, of course.** A counterexample is provided by a triplet of Normal variables (see [Marsaglia's paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwic-sPK-8rvAhXiz4UKHXomAw0QFjAFegQIDBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Fv16%2Fi04%2Fpaper&usg=AOvVaw0XAkcM4R4XOkR-IN8Jxqy0) in connection).

As a special case where the identity works, take the Dirichlet $\mathcal D(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d)$ distribution, whose expectation is
$$\mathbb E[Y_i]=\alpha_i\Big/\sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_j$$
One representation of a Dirichlet random vector $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_d)$ is
$$Y_i=\frac{X_i}{X_1+\ldots+X_d}\qquad X_i\sim\mathcal G(\alpha_i,1)$$
where the $X_i$'s are independent. In that case,
$$\mathbb E[Y_i]=\mathbb E[X_i\big/X_1+\ldots+X_d]=
\mathbb E[X_i]\big/\mathbb E[X_1+\ldots+X_d]$$

Comment: The identity will work whenever the $X_i$ are *iid* with nonzero expectation, as you basically pointed out in an earlier version of this answer.

Comment: @whuber: Is this enough to ensure that $X_1/(X_1+X_2)$ has a well-defined expectation?

Comment: Good question: I don't think so. For instance, let the distribution be uniform on the values $\{-1,1,3\}.$ $|X_1/(X_1+X_2)|$ equals one divided by zero with a chance of $2/9.$ Continuous approximations to this will have comparable problems. Notice that these random variables are (a) bounded and (b) have zero probability to be zero.

Comment: The expression like $X_1/(X_1 + X_2)$ also occured in this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/399952/ . There is an expression from Hinkley for the case that the $X_i$ are Gaussian distributed (and the expectation will be infinite). In this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438402 an intuitive view is given for the ratio distribution (and you could do the same for the correlated case). You could also express the distribution of the *angle*. And the expectation of the ratio is the expectation of the tangens of the angle, which becomes infinite when 90 deg has non-zero density.

Comment: When the $X_i$ are continuous and non-negative then the division by 0 occurs only in the point $(X_1,X_2) = (0,0)$ (which has zero probability) and for the other values of $X_1,X_2$ the value of the ratio $X_1/(X_1+X_2)$ is between 0 and 1, such that the ratio won't have infinite or undefined expectation.

Comment: Correct!, the expectation is defined since $X_1/(X_1+\cdots)\le 1$ with probability one.