# Picking an object from a random set

Tags: probability

The problem involves two selections one after the other. In the first selection we pick out a set of objects. And then in the second selection we pick out a particular object from this set.

Consider we have 3 sacks each containing $n_1$ red balls (distinct shades), $n_2$ blue balls (distinct shades) and $n_3$ green balls (distinct shades) respectively.  Consider $3$ independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ associated with the number of balls picked from each sack respectively (withput replacement) i.e  $X_1$ is the number of red balls picked ($0 \leq X_1 \leq n_1)$. The probabilities of picking a ball associated with each colours are $p_1,p_2,p_3$ respectively.

Now that we have defined how to pick a **set** of balls which itself is random, we define how to pick a ball of particular color and particular distinct shade form this **set** or not pick a ball at all.

The probability of picking a ball of particular distinct shade and colour, say a particular shade of RED without loss of generality (present in the set is):
$$q_{rl} =\frac{1}{\epsilon + X_1+X_2+X_3}$$

and not picking any ball is:

$$q_n=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + X_1+X_2+X_3}$$

Now what we want to find is the probability of picking up a ball which is RED (shade doesn't matter).
Thus the probability for that will be:
$$\sum_l q_{rl}$$
i.e the sum of all probabilities of picking any shade of red denoted by $l$ from the constructed set.

What we need is the value of $\mathbb E \big[\sum_l q_{rl} \big]$ i.e the expectation of the probability that the final ball in our hand is red.

It is given that:

$$\mathbb E \big[\sum_l q_{rl}\big] = \mathbb E\bigg[\frac{D_1}{\epsilon + D_1+D_2+D_3}\bigg]$$

where:

$$D_i = Binomial(n_i,p_i)$$

Intuitively this seems clear but I cannot show this formally. I also could not find any resorce to deal with division of random variables except [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515479/what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-division-of-a-random-variable-by-a-sum-of-rand), which seems insufficient here.

This is intuitive because, one way to write the probability of picking a ball of particular distinct shade and colour from our random set is (say RED):

$$q_{rl} =\frac{C_{rl}}{\epsilon + \sum_{i=1}^{n_1}C_{ri} + \sum_{j=1}^{n_2}C_{bj} + \sum_{k=1}^{n_3}C_{rk}}$$

where $C_{rl}$ will be $Ber(p_1)$, similarly if we had $C_{bl}$ it would be $Ber(p_2)$. Thus what we have is that picking a ball of particular color (say RED) is sum of Bernoulli random variables divided by sum of Bernoulli random variables $\frac{X_1}{\epsilon + X_1+X_2+X_3}$ which intuitively should be related to Binomial random variables, somehow.

Comment: Your description is rather ambigous. For example, what do you mean by "probability of not picking any ball"? If you put a hand into a bag to pick a ball and take one out, how can you "not pick" a ball at the same time? Probability of picking a ball of a particular color is $X_i / \sum_j X_j$, you have $X_i$ balls of this color and $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ balls in total. Hard to comment on your calculations as the whole procedure you are describing is not very clear.

Comment: @Tim the second part is not about picking from the sack. That was the 1st part. The second part is picking form a set, you can decide to pick up a ball or not pick up anything at all.

Comment: Then the missing information is about the probability of not picking anything at all, I assume this is given?

Comment: @Tim The probability is given of not picking any ball. From my persepective all tge probabilities seem well defined and summing upto 1. What is the missing information?

Comment: The question currently equivocates over whether $X_i$ are random variables or specific counts, and the $q$ terms sum to one only if $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ sum to three.

Comment: @jkpate $X_i$ are random variable. In the first line Is the overview of the question of picking from up a random set and then picking an object from the set. It doesn't sum to $3$. I have used $2$ subscripts $r,l$. Summing over $l$ will give me $X_1$. So summing over all $q$'s involve summing over 2 indices. One gives the $X_i$, the other sums to 1.