Statistical Inference for Quotients and Ratios
I have some data on RCTs where we are interested in calculating the ROI of an intervention. We are looking to compare the quotient of two totals per variation, as opposed to more conventional outcomes represented as a sum.
The major wrinkle is that we have no access to individual level data, only data aggregated to the variation.
Per variation we know the number of impressions $n$, the number of clicks $c$, and the number of conversions $k$. We also know how much in total we spent, $X$ and how much we made $Y$.
We want to compare
$$ Z = \frac{X}{Y} $$
per variation.
My instinct is to take logs and calculate
$$ \tilde{X_A} = \log(X_A) / n_A $$
$$ \tilde{Y_A} = \log(Y_A) / n_A $$
$$ \tilde{X_B} = \log(X_B) / n_B $$
$$ \tilde{Y_B} = \log(Y_B) / n_B $$
And then calculate:
$$ (Y_B - X_B) - (Y_A - X_A) $$
as a test statistic.
My Q:
Is this a valid approach? If so, how can I propagate the uncertainty to calculate confidence intervals, or find the (pooled) standard deviation?
Is there some wider literature on this sort of metric for RCTs?

A/B testing ratio of sums may be helpful

That link links back to this page, was this the one you meant? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398436/a-b-testing-ratio-of-sums
